# Render a react component n times

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button} from "@material-ui/core";
import Selector from "./Selector"

class Trigger extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicks: 0
    };
  }

  IncrementItem = () => {
    this.setState({
      clicks: this.state.clicks + 1
    });
  }

  DecreaseItem = () => {
    this.setState({
      clicks: this.state.clicks - 1
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <div>

        <Button
        onClick={this.IncrementItem}
        variant="contained"
        color='primary'>
        add
        </Button>

        {this.state.clicks ?
          <Button
          onClick={this.DecreaseItem}
          variant="contained"
          color='primary'>
          remove
          </Button>:
          null}

        {this.state.clicks ?
          <Selector>
          </Selector>:
          null}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Trigger;
```

Idea:

```
1. The first button increases this.state.clicks
2. The second button is shown only if this.state.clicks > 0
3. The second button decreases this.state.clicks
```

**Problem: render the Selector component n times (not only one time like in my code), where n=this.state.clicks.**

Note: the selector component is composed by 2 selectors and multiple options, so it's not a string-array.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Remove this.state.click part,  create one function and add for loop in that base where n =this.state.clicks = [number of click] and call that function inside your render

Comment: maybe something like this: {Array.from({length:this.state.clicks}).map((item,index)=><Selector key={index}/>)}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
    [...Array(this.state.clicks)].map((v, i) => <Selector key={`selector-${i}`} /> )
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! Should I consider this warning? "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Comment: @SkuPak Glad I could help. I updated the answer to fix the warning.